# How should I get tweets from more than one user in my app?

Tags: node.js, express, twitter

I am trying to create an app that would give the tweets from different users in one single page. Right now I am only able to generate the tweets from one user using the code below? What should I do if I want the tweets of more users in a single page?

Declare Requirements

```
var express = require("express"),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
errorHandler = require('errorhandler'),
Twitter = require('twitter'),
favicon = require('serve-favicon');

//Create the app
var app = express();

// Set up the views directory
app.set("views", __dirname + '/views');

// Set EJS as templating language, but allow for .html extension

app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

//Add connection to public folder for css & js files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/media/favicon.ico'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Set up Express error handling
app.use(errorHandler());

// Start the server

var server = app.listen(3000);
console.log('Express started on port: ' + 3000);

var TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxx';
var TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxx';
var TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY = 'xxx';
var TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET = 'xxx';

var client = new Twitter({
    consumer_key: TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumer_secret: TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    access_token_key: TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
    access_token_secret: TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET
});

/*--------------------------------------------
For this example, you need a twitter user's id
This site can help you with this
http://gettwitterid.com/
--------------------------------------------*/
var params = {
    user_id: ('428333')
};
```

I want to include the tweets of this user too in my app. How to do that? The user id I have written?

```
// var params1 = {
//  user_id: ('27260086')
// };

//ROUTES

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});

//Using the 'Twitter' lib - https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter


app.get("/search", function(req, res){
    client.get('statuses/user_timeline', params1, function(error, tweets, response){
        if (error){
            throw error;
        }
        console.log(tweets[0].text);
        var theTweet = {'tweet': tweets[0].text };
        res.json(theTweet);
    });
});


app.get("*", function(req,res){
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

I am new to node. Do i need to do something in my main javascript file?

Comment: If you want multiple tweets, why are you doing:
`var theTweet = {'tweet': tweets[0].text };  res.json(theTweet);`

Answer (score 0):

This should help you. Though you'll need to do better error handling and maybe formatting response as well.

Also, you'll have to optimize the code, as I've just pasted the code multiple times for users. I wont do that for you because I am lazy and you should learn to do those things.

```
var async = require("async");

app.get("/search", function (req, res)
{
    async.parallel([
        function ()
        {
            client.get('statuses/user_timeline', param1, function (error, tweets, response)
            {
                if (error)
                {
                    throw error;
                }
                callback(null,tweets);
            });
        },
        function ()
        {
            client.get('statuses/user_timeline', param2, function (error, tweets, response)
            {
                if (error)
                {
                    throw error;
                }
                callback(null,tweets);
            });
        }],
        function (err, results)
        {
            res.json(results);
        });
});
```